# Save active worksheet as Excel Binary

Tags: excel, vba

How may I tweak the code below to 1) Only Save the Active Worksheet (instead of entire Workbook) and 2) Save the file as an Excel Binary file?

I'm breaking my head over this... Many thanks

```
Dim FileName As String
FileName = Range("B2").Value

Dim fPth As Object
Set fPth = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

With fPth
  .initialFilename = FileName
  .Title = "Save your File"
  .FilterIndex = 2
  .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
  If .Show <> 0 Then
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=.SelectedItems(1), FileFormat:=xlExcel12
  End If
```

Comment: `xlExcel12` is the binary format, how is that not working?

Comment: I've written it so a "save file" window pops up, but it automatically selects "Macro enabled workbook" instead of "binary" format

Comment: Ok forget the Binary part.. how can I save the active worksheet only?

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Copy: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs...`  Copying a worksheet without giving it a destination creates a new workbook, which will then be the ActiveWorkbook.